# Java class for implementing a SAX Parser with inner classes

Tags: java, xml, sax

For a college assignment I need to write a SAX parser and a filter that reads the original XML file then creates a new modified one. The assignment requires that my program need to be run by console with "java Sax inputFileDestination OutputFileDestination" and it requires that there is only one file. I means I need to implement the interfaces with in the Sax.java. I am familiar with the inner classes but I dont know how to implement this with a main method in the outer class.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is an assignment, I'm not going to post any code, but explain how to do it.

I don't think you need an inner class at all to do this. Your class will have a main method, which creates a SAXParser, and registers itself (this) as a callback. You will then implement the SAX methods you desire (startElement, endElement, characters) from HandlerBase.

All your're doing is writing a SAXParser, and then tacking a main() method on it, so it will run from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a MySAXParser class with a usage outside in another class having a `main`. Then place that `main` method inside your MySAXParser class as test code.

XML Parsers deliver a jar with a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF using the SPI (Service Provider Interface). You might think of doing the same thing as a bonus.

Other inner classes can be `private static` if they are independent, or just `private` storing an extra outer `MySAXParser.this`; so one error often made is forgetting `static`.